# Nested SQL, finding which forums have posts of a certain type

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a SQL statement that I'm trying to run, but it's throwing an error:

```
SELECT fp.forum_id, COUNT(fp.forum_id) AS num_posts
FROM forums_posts fp
GROUP BY fp.forum_id
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(p.post_id) AS num_joined_posts
    FROM posts p
    WHERE p.post_type IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeC')
        AND p.forum_id = fp.forum_id
) > 0
ORDER BY num_posts DESC
```

The `forums_posts` table is a relational table matching forum IDs to post IDs, and the `posts` table (which also stores the post's forum ID) just contains info about each post. I am trying to find out: which forums have posts of the type TypeA, TypeB, or TypeC; and how many posts are in each of those forums.

Nested SQL statements have never been my strong suit. Can somebody point out the correct way to go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: What's the error TerranRich?

Comment: A very generic MySQL error: **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(p.post_id) AS num_joined_posts FROM posts p WHE' at line 4**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `where` should be before the `group by`.

You can also write this using an explicit `join`:

```
SELECT fp.forum_id, COUNT(fp.forum_id) AS num_posts
FROM forums_posts fp join
     (SELECT p.forum_id, COUNT(p.post_id) AS num_joined_posts
      FROM posts p
      WHERE p.post_type IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeC')
      group by p.forum_id
     ) p
     on p.forum_id = fp.forum_id
GROUP BY fp.forum_id
ORDER BY num_posts DESC
```

Although, I'm thinking the most efficient rendition might be:

```
SELECT fp.forum_id, COUNT(fp.forum_id) AS num_posts
FROM forums_posts fp join
GROUP BY fp.forum_id
having exists (select 1
               FROM posts p
               WHERE p.post_type IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeC') and
                     p.forum_id = pf.forum_id
               limit 1
              )
ORDER BY num_posts DESC
```

Particularly if you have an index on posts(forum_id, post_type).  I move the condition to the `having` clause from a `where` clause because there is presumably less data for this comparison after the grouping.

Comment: This is purely for reporting purposes, and is really a one-time use deal. I just wanted to know how it was done. Thanks for the multiple ideas though! At least I'm learning something, and I almost had it right. :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff + 1 for answer as well as that transition from `where` to `having`. Well [is this just useful or brilliant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords)? In a quest of getting a great feature :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT fp.forum_id, COUNT(fp.forum_id) AS num_posts
FROM forums_posts fp
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(p.post_id) AS num_joined_posts
    FROM posts p
    WHERE p.post_type IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeC')
        AND p.forum_id = fp.forum_id
) > 0
GROUP BY fp.forum_id
ORDER BY num_posts DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, SQL tends to be faster using a join.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT fp.forum_id,
       SUM(CASE p.post_type = 'TypeA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A_Count,
       SUM(CASE p.post_type = 'TypeB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_Count,
       SUM(CASE p.post_type = 'TypeC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C_Count
  FROM forums_posts fp
  LEFT JOIN posts p ON fp.forum_id = p.forum_id
  GROUP BY fp.forum_id
) T
WHERE T.A_count > 0 AND T.B_count > 0 AND T.C_count > 0
```

I have not tested this so it might have typos.